# How to check the duplicate records while importing excel file in to database using PHP

Tags: php, csv, duplicates

I need to check duplicate records in import excel. When I click import, duplicate records are also inserted into database table. I don't want to insert duplicate data in database table, but my code inserts duplicate records in database table.

This is my code

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST["import"])) {
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 120); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

    //$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    //$ext=substr($file,strrpos($file,"."),(strlen($file)-strrpos($file,".")));
    //if($ext=="csv")

    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $c = 0;
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle,",")) !== false)
    {
      //$filesop[] = fgetcsv($handle,",");
      $c++;

      if ($c == 1) { continue; }
      //$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[0]);
      $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[0]);
      $tags = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[1]);
      $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[2]);
      $url =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[3]);
      $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[4]);
      $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($filesop[5]));

      $check="SELECT * FROM `report` WHERE title='$title' AND url='$url'";
      $result=mysqli_query($conn,$check)or die($check."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)  //If no rows are returned
      {
        //print_r($filesop[0]);
        var_dump($filesop);
        //echo $filesop[0];

        $sql = "insert into report(category,tags,title,url,description,date) values ('$category','$tags','$title','$url','$description','$date')";

        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        //echo $sql;
        print_r($_FILES);
        // 
        //echo $filesop[1];

        //echo "success";
      }
      else
        echo "duplicates found";
    }
  //if($result){
  //echo " upload success";

    exit();

     //ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',FALSE);
    fclose($handle);

  // }
   //else
      // echo "cannot upload csv file"; 
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);      
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what is going wrong? What did you expect to see, and what do you see?

Comment: I don't  want to insert duplicate  data in database table .but my code inserts duplicate records in database table.

Comment: Let the database do the job. Just define a unique identifier and insert a unique column in your table. There you insert the identifier. So the database can handle unique entries and you can [update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) your database entries on duplicate key.

Comment: I have created unique index for title column and url column in my data base . but if my csv  file's 1 st row is the duplicate value   other  row  vaues are not inserting.

Comment: Have you read my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks a bit crazy. First of all you should let the database do the job. In nearly all use cases the database is faster than php. For this purpose define a unique column in your database table. In a unique column a value can be present one time only. With this you can update your entry on this duplicate unique key.

As shown in your code example you check on title and url. I 'd suggest to build a hash from title and url of your entry. This hash will be the unique identifier.

```
$identifier = hash('sha256', $title . $url);
```

With this unique identifier you can easily insert or update your database with one query.

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO 
        report 
        (category, tags, title, url, description, date, identifier) 
    VALUES 
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        category = VALUES(category),
        tags = VALUES(tags),
        description = VALUES(description),
";
```

In this example we are working with so called prepared statements. We do so, to execute your sql statement in a secury way. Furthermore we avoid calling these real escape functions we really don 't need when using prepared statements.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql);
if (!$stmt) {
    // error handling here
}

$result = $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', 
    $category, 
    $tags,
    $title,
    $url,
    $description,
    $date,
    $identifier
);
if (!$result) {
    // error handling
}

// executing the insert statement
$result = $stmt->execute();
if (!$result) {
    // error handling
}
```

Keep in mind, that you need a unique key index in your database table to use the on duplicate key update syntax. So create a new column "identifier" with a unique index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table_name(index_column_1);
```

Hope that helped you.